# C++ MFC visual studio fill combobox created dynamically

Tags: c++, dynamic, combobox, mfc

I try to fill a combobox that I have created dynamically using this code:

```
            hw = ::CreateWindowEx(0, _T("COMBOBOX")
            , NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | CBS_DROPDOWN
            ,gx, gy, w,h
            , this->m_hWnd, (HMENU)id, AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, NULL
            );
            LRESULT msg ;
            msg=::SendMessage(hw,CB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"test");
            if (msg = CB_ERRSPACE)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,((LPCTSTR)""),0);
            }
```

I always got a NULL value in msg, no item is added. Please What's wrong?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using unicode or ansi ? Also in your if you assign CB_ERRSPACE to msg, not compare to it.

Comment: I am using ansi, and indeed I was doing an affectation not test with CB_ERRSPACE..good remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out

```
SendMessage(hw, CB_INSERTSTRING, -1, (LPARAM)"test");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have corrected like you said  and I have also increased the h value which is the height of the combobx. So I realized that I can't display a long list (longer than the screen) to let the users to select a parameter. I thought I could use the combobox with a right lift. Do you confirm? thanks again

Comment: yea i think you can not have a combo longer than screen

Answer (score 0):

You Need to be aware that there is Unicode and MBCS Settings for a project.
I assume that your project has Unicode settings.

So you need to use _T or TEXT when you sue charater constants and want to use them in WinAPI functions.

```
msg=::SendMessage(hw,CB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)TEXT("test"));
if (msg = CB_ERRSPACE)
  MessageBox(NULL,TEXT(""),0);
```

The result msg==0 is OK. You added one item to the combobox. But due to the wrong encoding may not see the text you want to set.